# Limit character length for user submitted post in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a website where users submit content in the form of a post. Users don't have a text editor, just a form. I want to limit the length of their submitted posts. Can’t seem to find a WP function for that any where.

Comment: Is it an html form? If so, you can limit the number of characters allowed in the input field with `maxlength`.

Comment: @Geshode Thank you. That did the trick. I though it would be more complex where I would have to use php of Javascript.